# Javascript/Tiny Slider - Always show control button although no further item to scroll

Tags: javascript, slider, tiny-slider

I'm using tiny slider https://github.com/ganlanyuan/tiny-slider and if there are no items left to slide or in other words all are visible, the prev/next buttons disappear. How can I have the prev/next buttons always be visible?

That's my sript, and in some instances I'm rendering only 3 items but I would like to keep prev/next buttons if over 1450 width:

```
var slider_news = tns({
    container: '#news',
    mode: 'carousel',
    items: 1,
    responsive: {
        1450: {
            items: 3,
            gutter: 25
        },
        992: {
            items: 2
        },
    },
    mouseDrag: true,
    slideBy: 1,
    gutter: 20,
    loop: false,
    autoplayButtonOutput: false,
    nav: false,
    arrowKeys: true,
    speed: 500,
    controlsContainer: "#news-controls",
 });
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yh9sgvob/ ... where I use breakpoints 768 and 575. You see the buttons will appear if you narrow the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `freezable` option to `false`.

```js
var slider_news = tns({
    container: '#news',
    ...
    freezable: false,
 });
```

`freezable` is `true` by default. This indicates whether the slider controls (together with other functions. check [docs](https://ganlanyuan.github.io/tiny-slider/#options)) will be frozen/stop working when all slides can be displayed in one page.

**OTHER OPTIONS**

If you don't like the first option since that will also unfreeze other functions such as `loop`, etc. You can use css to always show the controls

```css
.tns-outer .tns-controls {
   display: block !important;
}
```

In your case, since you are already using `controlsContainer` option. You can just add a class with `display: block !important;`

```js
var slider_news = tns({
    container: '#news',
    ...
    controlsContainer: '#news-controls',
 });
```

```html
<div id="news-controls">
  <div>Left</div>
  <div>Right</div>
</div>
```

```css
#news-controls {
   display: block !important;
}
```